# Java client sending multiple requests instead of one

Tags: java, client-server

I'm setting up a basic client server program. Right now the client is simply sending an object with a command string in it to the server and the server is acknowledging it. This is done using a JFrame with buttons on it. It seems to work ok, except the client seems to be sending multiple requests instead of just one.

Inner class within my Client code:

```
private class CommandHandler implements ActionListener{
        FTPCommand c;
        ObjectOutputStream oos;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

            if (cmd == "DIR"){
                c = new FTPCommand("DIR");
            }
            if (cmd == "CHDIR"){
                String newDirectory = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter directory to change to:");
                c = new FTPCommand("CHDIR", newDirectory);
            }

            try {
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(c);
                oos.flush();
                //System.out.println("Command: " + c.getCommand() + ", sent successfully");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

}
```

Server:

```
public void run(){
        ObjectInputStream in;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            FTPCommand cmd = (FTPCommand) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("Received command: " + cmd.getCommand() + " at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

So if I click on the DIR button just once, this is the output I get, although sometimes it might just be one or two lines:

```
Received command: DIR at 1390572358017
Received command: DIR at 1390572365578
Received command: DIR at 1390572377229
```

Why is it sending multiple requests?

Comment: This is unrelated but isn't it a bad idea to check equivalence for Strings using the == operator instead of the equals() method?

Comment: Check whether there are any other actionPerformed calls in addition to the one you expect. Perhaps there is something else bound to an event. Change the code to do nothing if the command is neither DIR nor CHDIR (use else if/else or switch).

Comment: No other actionPerformed calls. What's weird is that the server has no loop. It doesn't allow any further clicks after the first one, as I'd expect. So how is it managing to print those 3 lines to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was the result of the client holding onto previous connections, and sending requests through all open sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Check inside the constructor of FTPCommand;  that how many time... it has been called... If thrice .... trace the calling methods.